Does std::unique_ptr automatically release memory when the object is released?
I have need of an object level variable (TIniFile* ini). In the past, the code samples and/or convention would be new/delete the object, like this:
frmMain.h
...
private:
  TIniFile* ini;
...

constructor
...
ini = new TiniFile(fileName);
...

destructor
...
delete ini;
...

I have been seeing alot about using std::unique_ptr() instead. Does this do what I think it does: automatically release memory when the object is released?
frmMain.h
#include <memory>
...
private:
  std:unique_ptr<TIniFile> ini;
...

constructor
...
ini = make_unique<TiniFile>(fileName);
...

no destructor

Long story short: yes. See here.

Yes, it does. If you show a [mre], then further improvements are possible.

yes ... if by "released" you mean when the object's destructor fires.

Sidenote: You could use the member initializer list MyClass::MyClass(String fileName) : ini(std::make_unique<TIniFile>(fileName)) {} to move construct ini instead of first default constructing it and then move assigning to it.

@3CxEZiVlQ I thought that I gave enough information for anyone familar with C++ std:: to understand.

@Ted Lyngmo: Not sure where I would put that. In the case of the TIniFile, I may not know the filename right away. But the question was kind of a general question about memory links and does this eliminate the leak. Thanks.

@JKofsky If you don't know fileName in the constructor, that's fine, you can leave the unique_ptr "empty", but if you do know it, then using the member initializer list is the idiomatic way to initialize member variables. Re: "Not sure where I would put that" - In your constructor, right after the ) and before the {, just add : and then the member variables you'd like to initialize, separated with a ,.

My first question is, do you really want to use dynamic allocation here? Maybe yes, but in many cases, this situation could be handeled using automatic variables.

@LokiAstari The vast majority of the VCL classes can't be automatic and actually must be dynamically allocated. I'm not sure about TIniFile but I'd bet it's one of those that can't be automatic. I see that the question is not tagged [tag:c++builder] but the name of the file and the class name says it is :)

My recommendation in conjunction with std::unique_ptr:  always use std::unique_ptr as your go-to first-best-choice owning smart pointer, and only use a raw pointer as a non-owning pointer.  Avoid using a raw pointer to an array, rather use a std::span as a non-owning "fat pointer" to an array.  And for collections, your first choice ought to be std::vector.  Good luck!

If smart pointer would not destroy the object then they would not be exceptions safe

@TedLyngmo yes, TIniFile is one of those classes that must be created dynamically. All TObject-derived (ie Delphi-based) classes must be. Also, the question was originally tagged as C++Builder but the tag got removed.

TObject ... oh myyy.  My code base was formerly Object Pascal (precursor to Delphi) converted into C++.  We have TObject too.


Does this do what I think it does: automatically release memory when the object is released?

Yes.  When the containing object is destroyed, it will destroy its unique_ptr member object, which in turn will destroy the TIniFile object it owns.

Thanks Remy. I was thinking I had cracked the code, but wanted to verify.

@JKofsky Worth noting that while the object is freed, the program may hold on to the actual memory. It takes time to give the memory back and even more to allocate it again if that storage is needed later. Modern computers gleefully trade memory for speed. It's common to see a program's memory go up and not appreciably go back down again.

@user4581301 But that behaviour is not specific to unique_ptr, the old way with manual memory management also keep the memory internally.

@user4581301 My main concern was memory leaks on prog running/termination.

@JKofsky Understood, but a frequent follow-up to a question like this goers something along the lines of "Ok, but if the object was destroyed, why didn't  didn't show I got my  bytes back?" Worth a quick comment to potentially save the asker their time.
